# What are some websites where I can search for public source code?

Tags: search, open-source

I know of [Google Code](http://code.google.com), which I presently use to search through publicly available source code.

However, is there a better website where I can search through public source code?  Specifically, it would be nice if I could easily locate code in Sourceforge and CodePlex.

Comment: http://nerdydata.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few questions which might be of interest to you! You can also check out the related questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90300/in-house-full-text-search-engine-for-source-code-and-sql-scripts

[What are the open source code search engines you know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156219/what-are-the-open-source-code-search-engines-you-know-about)

[Source code of big/popular websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239705/source-code-of-big-popular-websites)

Answer (score 0):

[koders.com](http://koders.com/)

[Google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch)